# error in asmethod(object) : cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

Tags: r

I already ran my program in the server. I think it is memory of R error problem. Two files are too big. D1 is 33694X43632, D2 is 33539X77777.

The error is:

> Error in asMethod(object) : 
>     Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

```
source('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jumphone/BEER/master/BEER.R')> colnames(D1)=paste0('D1_', colnames(D1))
> colnames(D2)=paste0('D2_', colnames(D2))
> DATA=.simple_combine(D1,D2)$combine
> BATCH=rep('D2',ncol(DATA))
> BATCH[c(1:ncol(D1))]='D1'
> PosN=apply(DATA,2,.getPos)
> USED=which(PosN>500 & PosN<4000)
> DATA=DATA[,USED]; BATCH=BATCH[USED] 
> mybeer=BEER(DATA, BATCH, GNUM=30, PCNUM=50, ROUND=1, GN=2000, SEED=1, COMBAT=TRUE, RMG=NULL) 
[1] "BEER start!"
[1] "2020-05-29 20:29:47 PDT"
[1] "Group number (GNUM) is:"
[1] 30
[1] "Varible gene number (GN) of each batch is:"
[1] 2000
[1] "ROUND is:"
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] "D1"
Performing log-normalization
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
Calculating gene variances
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
Calculating feature variances of standardized and clipped values
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
[1] 2
[1] "D2"
Performing log-normalization
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
Calculating gene variances
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
Calculating feature variances of standardized and clipped values
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
[1] "Total varible gene number (GN) is:"
[1] 3060
Performing log-normalization
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|
 Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Comment: what package(s) does your code use?

Comment: Hello BenBolker, It is jumphone/BEER. I think it is memory of R error problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you're already in conversation with the developer at https://github.com/jumphone/BEER/issues/6 ; I don't think anyone here is going to be able to help any better.